# Rust ownership rules in the context of closures

Tags: rust

I'm playing with the new closures in Rust and I ran into a situation that again showed me I didn't fully grasp the ownership rules yet.

```
#![feature(unboxed_closures)]
#![feature(overloaded_calls)]

fn main() {
    let mut test = 5i;
    let do_something = ref |:| { println!("{}", test) };
    test = 6i;
    do_something();

    println!("{}", test);
}
```

This code fails telling me that the assignment `test = 6i;` is invalid because `test` is already borrowed to the `do_something` closure.

But reading the *rules of ownership* (from the Rust Guide) it seems valid to me:

> 1.You control when that resource is deallocated.
>
> 2.You may lend that resource, immutably, to as many borrowers as you'd like.
>
> 3.You may lend that resource, mutably, to a single borrower. BUT
>
> 4.Once you've done so, you may not also lend it out otherwise, mutably or immutably.
>
> 5.You may not lend it out mutably if you're currently lending it to someone.

What is the problem with the code above. `test` is the owner and `do_something` should only have an **immutable** reference. Shouldn't it be legal to change the value of `test` if the only reference to it that we lend out to someone was *immutable*?

**FOLLOW UP**

Now that I learned that access by the owner also counts as lending I changed the code to use `Cell`.

```
#![feature(unboxed_closures)]
#![feature(overloaded_calls)]

use std::cell::Cell;

fn main() {
    let test = Cell::new(5i);
    let do_something = ref |:| { println!("{}", test) };
    test.set(6i);
    do_something();

    println!("{}", test);
}
```

But I wonder why this prints

```
5
6
```

and not

```
6
6
```

How would I need to change the code to print this?

```
6
6
```

Comment: Why did you write `|:|` rather than `||` ? I don't know exactly why, but it seems to make the difference you seek.

Comment: Ah you are write. `||` are still the old closures wheras `|:|` is one of the new ones and I thought `ref |:|` should be the new `||` closure type. I probably need to dig deeper :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you quoted yourself :

> You may not lend it out mutably if you're currently lending it to someone.

As you're already lending `test` to `do_something`, you cannot access it mutably before `do_something` goes out of scope.

Comment: Well but I don't want to lend it out *mutably*. The way I understand it `test` is the owner (not lending it) and it's only *lend* out *immutable* to `do_something`.

Comment: My understanding was that if there is only one owner that has *write access* to the data then I could have many lenders as long as they would only gain *read access*  to the data.

Comment: @Christoph no. You can lend mutably one time **or** immutably many times, but not both at the same time. And the owner accessing the data count as a lending.

Comment: Oh, the owner counts as lending. That was the missing bit for me. So does that mean if I want to do something like what I proposed it would always include using `RefCell`?

Comment: @Christoph Yes, that is a way.

Comment: Ok, thanks! I have one last follow up question that I directly edited into the question. May you help me one last time to get the puzzles connected? :)

Answer (score 2):

Answer to your follow-up:

This seems to happen because `Cell` is `Copy`, so it is copied into the closure. If you do this (now `ref` before the closure does not matter and can be omitted):

```
#![feature(unboxed_closures)]
#![feature(overloaded_calls)]

use std::cell::Cell;

fn main() {
    let test = Cell::new(5i);
    let test_ref = &test;
    let do_something = |:| { println!("{}", test_ref.get()) };
    test.set(6i);
    do_something();

    println!("{}", test.get());
}
```

Then it prints two `6`s.

However, I think this behavior is somewhat unexpected. I certainly would expect that closures with `ref` prefix will take *all* their environment by reference. I've just submitted an [issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/16814) for this.

Comment: Thanks! I also thought that the `ref |:|` was the same as the old `||`. Interested to see the feedback on the issue on the ticket that you created.

Comment: @Christoph, as far as I remember, `|:|` syntax is for `FnOnce` closures; it's `ref |&mut:|` closure is what is supposed to be the same as old `||` one. Again, as far as I remember, the idea was to drop old closures and use their syntax as a shorthand for `|&mut:|`.

Comment: Ah ok, but even that prints `5, 6`

Comment: Yes, I don't think that would make any difference in this case.